# Inserting into a populated table

Tags: oracle

I am working on a oracle project, but I have come across this error and can't figure it out. So i have created a table "Drugs" and I have 4 columns. They are as follows: (D_id, D_name, D_Date_of_Exp, D_price). I had populated the first 3 columns and forgot to populate the 'D_price' column with values.

So, now when I tried to insert data into it again:

```
insert into drugs(d_id, d_price) values(50, 400)
```

gave me this error:
**ORA-00001: unique constraint (PARTH.SYS_C007100) violated**

I know what causes the error above, my question is, how can I get around that error and insert the prices that match with the 'D_id' in my table.

So, I tried this:

```
insert into drugs(d_price) values(400)
where d_id = 50;
```

gave me this error: **ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended**

Still lost. Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your table already populated, and you missed D_PRICE to populate while inserting data into table. Now It's time to update the record, use the SQL like:

```
update drugs set d_price = 400
where d_id = 50;
```

Comment: That works! Is there a way to do multiple updates at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can use like,    update drugs set d_price = decode(d_id,50,400,60,500,70,800) where d_id in (50,60,70)  ......... or you can use the case statement if the values are static for updates, or else you can use the join in update

Comment: You can mark the question answered if the information is useful to you